# How to navigate from one tab to another tab by clicking on a button in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, tabs

I have a page that has consist of different tabs and each tab has a 'next button' through which the user can only be redirected to another tab based on some validations(Yes we can directly click on every tab but this is a specific use case). I have used `<tabs>` component which contains a value for each tab like this:

```
<tab value=1 header="abc">
<abc></abc>
```

Under route.js each tabs has been routed to different components like path:

```
'/abc' component:Abc.
```

How can this be achieved?